# CMake: install(DIRECTORY) and files with no extension

Tags: cmake

I have a problem with `install(DIRECTORY` FILE_MATCHING in cmake. I want to get all files which have the file extension`*.h` or no file-extension. I've using the following code, which does not work because it seems that every `PATTERN`is calculated with an OR (boolean operation) and `*` is a wild card for every file, an so every file is copied.

```
install(DIRECTORY mydir
    DESTINATION .
    FILE_MATCHING
    PATTERN "*.h"
    PATTERN "*"
```

Does anybody know how i can filter that scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter

```
PATTERN "*"
```

actually matches **any file**.

For match only **files without extension** you may use *REGEX*-based filter:

```
REGEX "/[^.]+$"
```

Comment: Thx. That works. 2 Minutes after my initial post i found the REGEX command, but i have tried to find the correct expression. Yours works fine, but what irritating me is that my regex works on regexr.com and regex101.com but not in cmake => "^[^.]+$", do you know why my regex does not work in cmake, what so special about the / in cmake regex?

Comment: In CMake, *PATTERN* is applied only to *last component* of the path (that is, without directories), but *REGEX* is applied to **full path**. From [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/install.html) for `install` command: "A `REGEX` will match any portion of the full path but it may use `/` and `$` to simulate the `PATTERN` behavior."

Comment: Good to know. Thx for that